# How to combine files

Tags: 14.04

I listen to audiobooks as I work around the house. Most audiobooks come in many "pieces" ... multiple MP3 files. I need to combine these files into one large file to properly use it. In windows there are several "merge" file but I haven't found anything for Ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try to use `Audacity` (you can install it using the `Software Center`). However, it has a lot more features than combining several files and it is possibly not very easy to use unless you are used to it.